# MySQL Query Help - translating tag functionality to SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm currently trying to convert the functionality of my website from utilizing php and text files to utilizing a MySQL database. I have the database setup and tables filled in.

**The database contains the following:**

```
Table: Items
Columns: Item_ID, Item_Name

Table: Tags
Columns: Tag_ID, Tag_Name

Table: Items_Tags
Columns: Item_ID, Tag_ID
```

**How do I create the following queries?**

1) Return the names of all items that have 4 or more of the same tags as an item named 'x'.

> For example, say an item x has tags a,b,c,d,e,f and item y has tags a,b,c,d then i need to return y and others that have at least 4 of the same tags as x

2) Return the names of the tags that 2 items have in common

> Expanding on the one above, using x and y, return a,b,c,d since they have those in common

3) Return the names of the items that have the following tags 'a','b','c'

> x and y would be returned because they have a,b,c as tags

**My attempts so far**

*Removed because they weren't even close*

Comment: Why the MS SQL Server tag? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: It was an error, and I just removed it.

Comment: Nope just trying to convert my website to utilize a database instead of nested for loops and text files lol but query creation is a lot more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
select i.Item_Name,
count(distinct t.Tag_Name) as tag_count
from Items i join Items_Tags it on i.Item_ID = it.Item_ID
join Tags t on it.Tag_ID = t.Tag_ID
where i.Item_Name = 'X'
group by i.Item_ID
having count(distinct t.Tag_Name) >= 4;
```

Comment: When I run that query it just shows x's name with the number of tags x has.

Comment: Yes, that's cause of the `WHERE` condition cause in your post you said *with a specific Item_Name = 'x'*. Remove that condition if you don't want it.

Comment: I think I worded it incorrectly. Return the names all items that have 4 or more of the same tags as an item named 'x'. BTW, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

#1

```
select i.item_name, t.tag_name,
count(t.tag_tame) as tag_count
from items i, tags t, items_tags it
where i.item_id = it.item_id
and t.tag_id = it.tag_id
and Upper(i.item_name) = Upper('x')
group by i.item_name, t.tag_name
having count (it.tag_id) >= 4
```

#2

```
select i.item_name, t.tag_name
from items i, tags t, items_tags it  
where i.item_id = it.item_id
and t.tag_id = it.tag_id
and Upper(i.item_name) like Upper(:item_name)    /* :item_name acts as  parameter and let you send any item_name you need */
group by t.tag_name, i.item_name
having count (it.tag_id) >= 1
```

#3

```
select i.item_name, t.tag_name
from items i, tags t, items_tags it  
where i.item_id = it.item_id
and t.tag_id = it.tag_id
and ((Upper(t.tag_name) = Upper('a')) or
     (Upper(t.tag_name) = Upper('b')) or
     (Upper(t.tag_name) = Upper('c')))
group by t.tag_name, i.item_name
```

Comment: The count(t.tag_tame) is only showing 1 even when there are multiple occurrences of a tag so an empty result is being returned. I also don't see where it compares the tags of all other items to the tags of 'x'.

Comment: try post sample data for the 3 tables because it should normally return only for count of tags greater than or equal to 4

Comment: For #1 the tag_count is still staying at 1 and now only showing the tags for x. For #2 how can I specify a specific 'x' and 'y' for the item names?

Comment: For #3 it works for getting items that have 1 tag but you include more than 1, it gives you items that don't have all 3 but have 1 out of the 3.